# 401 error , Authorization has been denied for this request

Tags: c#, .net, oauth, owin

Recently I upgraded .net frame work from 4.6 to 4.7.2 and after that existing Bearer tokens stopped working when call the existing REST APIS and returning the error "authorization has been denied for this request" .when I create a new token it works . Was there any upgrade on encryption/decryption for 4.7.2 rather than 4.6 ?

Comment: Did you happen to update any Nuget packages too?

Comment: @Crowcoder just 4.7.2 and re-started the server

Comment: Bearer tokens should not be valid for long periods of time so how much do you really need pre-existing ones to work?

Comment: @Crowcoder it wasnt related to how old they are , even the tokens got created obe day before the migration had the same issue

Comment: That's not what I'm saying. I'm saying you should not *allow* tokens to be valid for a long time for security reasons. So by now your problem should have gone away. But I think it is very likely the implementation has changed. Exactly what token library are you using? It is probably open source and you could look and see what has changed.

Comment: @Crowcoder I'm using OWIN , and the issue is gone now by creating new tokens , but I'm trying to figure out how it happened and how framework upgrade can change the token validation policy